# How do I address my juniors in college or school?

Tags: translation

If "senpai" means someone's senior, then if I am the senior what do I call my freshman i.e. the one who is younger than me in the same school or something. How do I address them?

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/can-sempai-be-used-to-address-a-student-of-the-same-year-age/13387#13387

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address younger kids in your school, you use their names and nicknames.  You DO NOT address them as [後輩]{こうはい} unless it is jokingly done (and it is rarely done).

However, younger kids can address YOU as [先輩]{せんぱい} either all by itself or by combining it with your family name like [山本先輩]｛やまもとせんぱい｝.

Comment: ok thats the answer i was looking for.
Now assume this situation which happened to me in real life. I know someone am her senpai in university
,then i started taking a japanese course recently i found out that she is at the last level of that course, so she is my senpai at that course . Now i always call her with her name + san . Should i call her at that course senpai and in college her name + san
or just keep calling her "name + san" and thats ok?

Comment: Among us Japanese, what matters most is the school year one belongs to.  If a person is taking a particular subject at a more advanced level is of little importance with regards to how he should be addressed.  So, you could call her "name + さん" all the time.  However, this is no simple question because you guys are not Japanese or you live in Japan.

Comment: yes i live in egypt it is different. The thing is we are trying to talk japanese as much as we can to practise so thats why i asked . thanks :D